# Get NSData from block

Tags: objective-c-blocks

Trying to get data from block, but NSLog(localData) shows nil.
How to get data from block?

```
    __block NSData *localData = nil;
        JBContainedURLConnection *connection = [[JBContainedURLConnection alloc] initWithURLString:flightsURLStr userInfo:nil completionHandler:^(JBContainedURLConnection *connection, NSError *error, NSString *urlString, NSDictionary *userInfo, NSData *data) {

            if (nil != error) {

                // Handle the error.
                // A nil error indicates success!
                NSLog(@"Error! %@", [error userInfo]);
                return;
            }
            localData = [NSData dataWithData:data];
             }];

NSLog(localData);
```

Comment: When are you logging `localData`? Are you doing it definitely after the completion handler has run?

Comment: Yes, after the completion handler has run. In block data is not nil, so I'm trying to get it out

Comment: If you log `localData` after you set it in the completion handler, does it show as non-nil?. Also note that the code you added to log `localData` in the question if that's where you have the `NSLog` in your code, then that won't necessarily (in fact extremely unlikely) run after the completion handler has run. You're aware of that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is Jason Brennan's [NSURLConnection wrapper class](https://github.com/jbrennan/JBContainedURLConnection) that you are using:

That is an asynchronous call that is a wrapper around the normal NSURLConnection asynchronous loading mechanism. The completion block will fire on this same thread after this method has returned and after you've tried to log the data.

You can put an NSLog statement in the completion block and you will see that it fires after you attempt to log the data.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I need it out of the block, where NSLog(localData) stands now

Comment: I understand, but you won't get it at that point in the code. The block hasn't run yet.

Comment: You can process that data within the block, set an ivar, or call another method to process your data, etc.

Comment: I can't process data inside the block. Calling method from inside hangs an application.

Comment: Found solution in E.Sadun Cookbook:
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
         localData = [NSData dataWithData:data];   
        }];

Answer (score 0):

Found solution in E.Sadun Cookbook:

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{ 
localData = [NSData dataWithData:data]; 
}];
```

Comment: Block in a block... blockception!